# What could cause writing a pointer address to std::cout to crash?

Tags: c++, pointers, cout

Whenever I output a particular pointer address to `std::cout`, I get a crash:

```
bool MyClass::foo() const
{
  std::cout << "this prints fine" << std::endl << std::flush;
  std::cout << d << std::endl << std::flush;  // crash!
  return true;
}
```

Where `d` is a pointer member of the class, i.e.:

```
class MyClass {
// ... 
 private:
  MyClassPrivate* d;
};
```

**What could cause the application to crash?** Even if it is a NULL pointer, or an initialized pointer, it should still print out the (perhaps invalid) address, right?

The application is compiled in debug mode, if that makes a difference. The function `foo` is not marked as inline.

*Background: I am trying to track down a bug in an external application process. The bug is only caused when another application sends rapid-fire command to the process. I'm using `std::cout` to trace the execution of the external process.*

Comment: maybe you have operator<< (ostream&, MyClassPrivate*) defined? that will cause it to be called

Comment: Can you tell if the crash is in `operator<<` or right in `foo()`?

Comment: *Aside*: `std::endl` already performs an `std::flush`. The `std::flush`es in your code are redundant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `this` is not a valid pointer, any access to a member field might cause an access violation. Non-virtual methods called on invalid pointers work just fine until they try to access a field, because the call itself doesn't need to dereference `this`.

For instance, this situation would crash roughly as you describe:

```
MyClass* instance = nullptr; // or NULL if you're not using C++11
instance->foo(); // will crash when `foo` tries to access `this->d`
```

Comment: To test for this theory, add `std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl`.

Comment: Thanks, that appears to be the case: `std::cout << (void*)this << std::endl` also fails. I should have paid more attention to "Inside the C++ Object Model." :)

Answer (score 4):

There could be an overload of `operator<<(ostream &, MyClassPrivate*)`, that dereferences the pointer. For example there certainly is if `MyClassPrivate` is really `char`.

Try `std::cout << (void*)d;`, see whether or not it makes a difference. If not, zneak's answer seems plausible.